# Flashing screen although I do my alerts on main thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, uialertview

I know UIKit stuff should be done on mian thread, that's why, I ensure my alert view are showing up on the main thread.

```
-(void)showAlert:(NSString *)alertMessage{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertMessage message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [alert show];
    });

}
```

However, when I dismiss the alert, the screen becomes flashing. So that didn't fix my issue, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the show alert method form a background thread, please try using

```
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAlert:) withObject:alertMessage waitUntilDone:YES];
```

for the method call and change your showAlert method to

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertMessage message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert show];
```

Comment: Hi, I already tried this way before posting my question, but it doesn't help at all, still getting a flashing screen everywhere after dismissing the `alert`.

Comment: Ok, Then are you sure this is caused because of threads? It could be caused by some other reasons as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you allocate UIAlertView into main thread? Also with your solution you have memory leak. Try this:

```
-(void)showAlert:(NSString *)alertMessage{


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertMessage message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release]
    });

}
```

Also "OK" text actually should be cancel button in your case.

Comment: Hi, My project is ARC, don't need to release my object.

Answer (score 0):

Write the following code where you would like to show the UIAlertView with the appropriate Title and Message within the msgDict .

```
    NSMutableDictionary *msgDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [msgDict setValue:@"Title for AlertView" forKey:@"Title"];
    [msgDict setValue:@"Message within the AlertView" forKey:@"Message"];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAlert:) withObject:msgDict  
                        waitUntilDone:YES];
```

program control reaches within the showAlert method then

```
    -(void)showAlert:(NSMutableDictionary *)msgDict
      {
           UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] 
                       initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[msgDict objectForKey:@"Title"]] 
                             message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[msgDict objectForKey:"Message"]]
                            delegate:nil 
                   cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                   otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
           [alert show];
      }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanx for that, can you explain why the use of `NSMutableDictionary` ?

Comment: Hi Malloc, I have used the NSMutableDictionary here in order to pass more and more values to the Method ShowAlert: . It could be more useful if you are willing to send Multiple OtherButtonTitles within the UIAlertView. Also without using the Dictionary you would not be able to send multiple argument using performSelectorOnMainThread: